# Adding views programmatically to custom module in drupal 7

Tags: drupal, drupal-7, drupal-views

I am a newbie and have started writing modules. I need to add multiple views in 1 module. I have added 1 view using hook_views_api() and hook_views_data(). Please can anybody help in adding more views in single module?

Comment: Can anybody please suggest?

Answer (score 1):

This topic has been dormant for a number of years but has had no proper answer. So allow me.

The problem above is that you are listing your views in the same file, which is messy and unorganized. Below is a more appropriate and straightforward way of doing things.

Firstly i suggest creating a folder in your module directory, for example **"YOUR_MODULE/views/"**.

Then for each view you would like to import you will create a new file such as **"my_view.inc"** with one file being one view. This makes it easier to find the view your looking for if you need to make changes later on.

Then is to declare which api you will use for your imports.

```
 /**
 * Implements hook_views_api().
 */
function YOUR_MODULE_views_api() {
  return array(
    'api' => '3.0',
  );
}
```

Once you have declared the api version you will need the following below.

```
/**
 * Implements hook_views_default_views().
 */    
function YOUR_MODULE_views_default_views() {
  $views = array();
  $path = drupal_get_path('module', 'YOUR_MODULE') . '/views/*.inc';

  foreach(glob($path) as $file) {
    require_once $file;
    $views[$view->name] = $view;
    unset($view);
  }

  return $views;
}
```

What this does is look for all the "my_view.inc" files inside the subdirectory and will load them all automatically after a Clear Cache.

Hope this helps those who are still stuck.

Answer (score 0):

Be sure to declare [hook_views_api()](http://api.drupal.org/api/views/views.api.php/function/hook_views_api/7) or this hook won't get fired.

But you do this via [hook_views_default_views()](http://api.drupal.org/api/views/views.api.php/function/hook_views_default_views/7)

In [Views](http://drupal.org/project/views), you create the View you would like to include in the module.  Then you use function hook_views_default_views() and attach the export code (from views) like so:

```
function yourmodulename_views_default_views() {
  // Begin copy and paste of output from the Export tab of a view.
  $view = new view;
  // ..yadda yadda yadda

  // Add view to list of views to provide.
  $views[$view->name] = $view;

  // Begin copy and paste of output for another view
  $view = new view;
  // ..yadda yadda yadda

  // Add view to list of views to provide.
  $views[$view->name] = $view;

  return $views
}
```

The return $views at the end of the function will return all of the views for you.

Comment: Thanks a lot. But I have been writing views code and not exporting. Added my code in question for reference.

Comment: Sorry, I would normally export the code first, and then place it in a module - but it seems you are writing from scratch... is there a particular reason why you're writing from scratch?

Comment: Its a totally custom module. The tables are made by my code which are not exposed to views otherwise.